# Execute SSIS Package in Azure VM from Data Factory

Tags: azure, ssis, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to execute an SSIS package from a Data Factory pipeline where the SSIS packages are deployed to an existing SQL Server instance on a VM also in Azure?

I looked into creating a self-hosted integration runtime but this is only data migration related.  Also looked at executing a stored procedure but there is no returned value on success/fail etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to Microsoft and they confirmed you cannot run or trigger SSIS packages that are not hosted in the Azure Integration Runtime.  No plans to change that anytime soon.